# What should I do when someone posts a question about phishing or malware?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I recently stumbled across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72188773/phishing-email-javascript

Now, I know that the question is poor quality due to posting code as an image - so I downvoted accordingly. However, I'm in a quandary as to what the next cause of action would be.

I was initially going to do the generic "Please post code as text" style comment; but then it dawned on me that the code in question is part of a phishing/malware email received by the user, so I'm not sure that I should advise that course of action due to not knowing the repercussions of that likely malicious code.

I can't find anything evident in the flag reasons related to malicious code - so do I flag it as in need of moderator intervention? Or do I just treat as if it were any other question?

Comment: There is no general issue with asking about viruses/malware: [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656)

Comment: Indeed. But this is not a programming question, it is merely a question about a shady attachment which happens to be code.

Comment: Ahh, OK - so it's kinda just treat it as a normal question if they state that the code is malicious.